# stylesheet not getting applied in internet explorer using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html, iframe

Hello i am facing problem in all IE browser, I am loading iframe inside div using js code but  somehow the css classes are not getting applied inside my iframe components like textbox, buttons,etc. . the same code works for chrome and forefox , only IE is creating problems. my code is like...

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var myCSS = document.createElement("link");
    myCSS.rel= "stylesheet";
    myCSS.type= "text/css";
    myCSS.href= Url + "/public/css/mycss.css";
    head.appendChild(myCSS);



//for IE
if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent("onload", function() {
                var divforIframe = document.createElement("div");
                divforIframe.id = "divforIframe";
                var i = document.createElement("iframe");
                i.id = "myIFrame";
                i.src = Url;
                i.scrolling = "no";
                i.frameborder = "0";
                i.width = "500px";
                i.height = "300px";
                divforIframe.appendChild(i);
                document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(divforIframe);
    });
}
```

Comment: Does the Url variable point to a folder? At the beginning your code is the following `Url + "/public/css/mycss.css"` and then when you specify the iframe src it is just `Url`. Just checking :)

Comment: yup it points to the exact url  as in chrome and FF its working...:)

Comment: It might be helpful if you could replicate the issue in a jsfiddle.